# How to hide default error message(Traceback) in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, error-handling, traceback

I wanted to know how to hide errors in python:
Let's say I made a calculator and then typed:

```
if number1 != int:
     print("NaN")
```

But it will print this message and give out the error which is built into python which is:
Traceback (most recent call last):

but how do I hide this Traceback error and only show the error message which is "NaN"

Thank you for the answer.

Comment: ```if number1 != int:``` makes no sense. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you are talking about `try...except`, the following statement makes no sense.

You telling python to compare 1 to data type `int`

```
if number1 != int: print("NaN")
```

If you want to check a particular data type, use `isinstance(<variable>,<data type>)`

```
if isinstance(number1,int): print("NaN")
```

---

You can use `try...except` method to catch various errors:

```
try:
    number1=int(input("Enter a number: "))
    ...
except ValueError:
    print("NaN")
```

Note that this will catch only `ValueError`. If you want to catch all errors, use `except Exception` or `except:`

Comment: Ohk thank you so much! Sorry for the incorrect meaning in the code.

Comment: @kronox, no problem

Answer (score 0):

To "hide" a Error message (NameError) you can try the following, but this is only because `number1` is not defined:

```py
try:
    if number1 != int: print("NaN")

except NameError:
    print("Error is hidden!")

except:
    print("Catch all other Exceptions!")
```

For more see the following [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp).

I think you want to check if the inserted numer is not an integer. This can be done with the following code:

```py
number = "asdf"

if type(number) != int: 
    print("NaN")

else:
    print("Valid number!")
```